# Running dash app in azure functions python model v2 but only getting default site up page

Tags: python, azure-functions, wsgi

I'm using the v2 python programming model and trying to launch a dash app similar to the example of a Flask app [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python?tabs=wsgi%2Capplication-level&pivots=python-mode-decorators#alternative-entry-point)

my function_app.py is as follows:

```
import dash
from dash import dcc
from dash import html
import azure.functions as func

dashapp = dash.Dash()
colors = {
    'background': '#111111',
    'text': '#7FDBFF'
}
dashapp.layout = html.Div(
    style={'backgroundColor': colors['background']}, 
        children=[
            html.H1(
                children='Hello Dash',
                style={
                    'textAlign': 'center',
                    'color': colors['text']
                }
            ),
            html.Div(children='Dash: A web application framework for Python.', style={
                'textAlign': 'center',
                'color': colors['text']
            }),
            dcc.Graph(
                id='Graph1',
                figure={
                    'data': [
                        {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [4, 1, 2], 'type': 'bar', 'name': 'SF'},
                        {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [2, 4, 5], 'type': 'bar', 'name': u'Montréal'},
                    ],
                    'layout': {
                        'plot_bgcolor': colors['background'],
                        'paper_bgcolor': colors['background'],
                        'font': {
                            'color': colors['text']
                        }
                    }
                }
            )
    ]
    )

app = func.WsgiFunctionApp(app=dashapp.server.wsgi_app, 
                        http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)
```

My host.json is:

```
{
"version": "2.0",
"logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
    "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
    }
    }
},
"extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[3.15.0, 4.0.0)"
},
"functionTimeout": "00:10:00",
"extensions": 
{
    "http": 
    {
        "routePrefix": ""
    }
}
}
```

When I run locally it works as expected with my app at `http://localhost:7072/` but when I deploy to Azure functions and go to `myapp.azurewebsites.net` then I just get the your app is up and running page.  My guess is that Azure is serving that at the root address regardless of my app but the local deployment doesn't but I don't know how to verify that or, more importantly, change that behavior.

Comment: I think this should be [deployed as a traditional App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-python) rather than an Azure Function. What is the reason to try and deploy this as an Azure Function?

Comment: As I can see, the same question you have raised in Q&A Forum #[1161595](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1161595/running-dash-app-in-azure-functions-python-model-v), and as per my research I found that can deploy dash python app to the Docker as well as Azure App Service from this [article](https://www.phillipsj.net/posts/deploying-dash-to-azure-app-service/).

Comment: @holger because it's going to be a small dash so I don't need an "app service" running 24/7.  I just want it to run as a function.

Comment: @HariKrishna thanks for your research but I'm not trying to run it in app service.

Comment: Were you able to solve the issue?

> My guess is that Azure is serving that at the root address regardless of my app but the local deployment doesn't but I don't know how to verify that or, more importantly, change that behavior.

If I understand the issue, this looks like your app isn't getting indexed. After you deployed the app, did you also set the applications setting (set the `AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags` environment variable to have this value: `EnableWorkerIndexing`)

Answer (score 0):

As @*vrdmr* and @*MughundhanRaveendran-MSFT* suggested that the base URL of Azure Functions states that the Function is in Running State in the MS Q&A #[1161595](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1161595/running-dash-app-in-azure-functions-python-model-v)

- Whatever the Language Runtime APIs we are deploying/publishing to Azure Functions, that Function API Name should be suffixed with the Azure Function base URL.
- It can be local host Function URL or published Azure Function URL, Function API name is suffixed with the base address.
- For the Local host Azure Functions Running, the format will be (localhost + Port + Function API Name (Http Context based trigger) and (Azure base function URL + Function API name + Authorization key-value if Authorization is defined such as Anonymous, Function or Admin or Custom)

[image]

- Also, Make Sure a new application setting is added to the Python V2 model in Azure Function App in the Portal Menu, will be available by default in the local Project `local.settings.json` i.e., `AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags:EnableWorkerIndexing`.

[image]